# Why is a scala Set casted to a Vector instead of a List?

Tags: scala, types, scala-collections

I wonder why a `Set[A]` is converted to a `Vector[A]` if I ask for a `Seq[A]` subclass? To illustrate this take the following example:

```
val A = Set("one", "two")
val B  = Set("one", "two", "three")

def f(one: Seq[String], other : Seq[String]) = {
  one.intersect(other) match {
    case head :: tail => head
    case _ => "unknown"
  }
}

f(A.to, B.to)
```

This function will return "unknown" instead of one. The reason is that `A.to` will be casted to a `Vector[String]`. The cons operator (`::`) is not defined for Vectors but for Lists so the second case is applied and "unknown" is returned. To fix this problem I could use the `+:` operator which is defined for all `Seqs` or convert the Set to List (`A.to[List]`). So my (academic) question is:

Why does `A.to` returns a Vector. At least according to the [scala docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) the default implementation of `Seq` is `LinearSeq` and the default of this is `List`. What did I got wrong?

Comment: As I wrote: I can totally do this and it works as a charm. My question is not how to fix this but why does it behave like that.

Comment: Random sample PR on this question: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4175

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ha, yes, use the words, "Because that is what you asked for." Or as you put it, "if you want a list...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it can, you are depending on runtime class implementation details, instead of compile-time type information guarantees. The `to` or `toSeq` method is free to return anything that typechecks, it could even generate a random number and chose a concrete class in base of that number, so you may get a **List** something other times a **Vector** or whatever. It may even decide in base of the operating system. Of course, I am being pedantic here and hopefully, they do not do that, but my point is, we can't really explain, that is what the implementation does and it may change in the future.

Also, the *"default implementation of **Seq** is a **List**"*, applies only in the constructor. And again, they may change that in any moment.

So, if you want a **List** ask for a **List**, not for a **Seq**.